# HTML Purifier convert & -> &amp;

Tags: php, yii2, htmlpurifier

i'm using HTML Purifier(Yii2) in my text field.

I need save "&" in original, but purifier convert to "&amp";

I don't want use `str_replace` after purifier.

Can you help me with configuration?

my config:

```
['name'],
'filter',
'filter' => function($value) {
    return HtmlPurifier::process($value, [
        'HTML.SafeObject' => true,
        'HTML.SafeEmbed' => true,
        'Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters' => true,
        'Core.Encoding' => 'UTF-8'
    ]);
}
```

**UPD:**

Example of text, what i want purify: "Company name & Co"

Comment: Why do you need to save `&` in the original? What context are you purifying for?

Comment: (If you want to know why I'm asking, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37641037/245790 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26128263/245790.)

Comment: Why? HTML permits `&` to be presented as a literal character when followed by a space.

Comment: Whether or not it's permitted, &amp; isn't a problem if the context is html output, so @pinkgothic's question is still pertinent.

Comment: @pinkgothic, i added context what i want purify and save in my DB.
i understand that it's not good way. I save in original , because i used this text when dispay company name and send message to user.

Comment: @BogdanGudyma Please don't purify before you put something into your database, purify when you output your data as HTML. It will save you a lot of headaches (see the first link). That said: After looking around, I don't see a way to make HTML Purifier ignore `&` in particular. This was once discussed on the HTML Purifier fora: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,4655 - from a couple of years ago, but seems to still be true. The 'suggestion' there was to replace `&` with something unique that won't get changed, then swap back after purification, but that's of course not robust. Sorry.

Comment: @pinkgothic, thank you for your attention, i try resolve my problem another way.  Give your links and create your answer, i will mark this answer as right

Comment: Had the same case. I use purifier not to create sanitied html, but to escape probable xss. So I use `$content = \str_replace(['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;'], ['&', '<', '>'], $content);` after doing a purify with the option `HTML.Allowed = ''`. I store the output in database (I'm aware about data loss) and the data is used in many tools, also legacy tools I can't rely on their escaping methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you're purifying before entering information into your database.

I recommend you *rethink this* from an architectural point of view, as it has a couple of shortfalls, such as that you lose your original user input (which you may later want to analyse for any one reason), that your database becomes less useful once you want to do something else with the data, and that bugs in your current version of HTML Purifier (which may be security relevant) won't be ironed out. You can see more information about the importance of **escaping/sanitising for context** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641037/245790).

That said, your problem has been previously discussed on the HTML Purifier fora: [Do not escape ampersand](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,4655). The thread discusses why it's difficult to treat `&` differently and remain secure and essentially 'recommends' not using HTML Purifier, which of course doesn't solve your problem.

Nonetheless, there are suggestions and thoughts from within that thread which may help you if you're forced to store purified HTML in your database:

> Perhaps a more useful response would be: store the raw, user submitted data (without running HTML Purifier on it) in the database, and run search queries on that. However, store in the database as well a cached version of the HTML Purified version.

Or (this uses `<` as an example):

> No such boolean flag exists, and it would be reasonably tricky to implement safely (you'd want to do something silly like convert literal < and friends to some unforgeable piece of text and then convert &lt; to the literal version.)

But latter is not a robust approach and former is an unnecessary redundancy.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, per se, but I'm surprised there's no comment about why. If the downvoter sees this, could you explain why?