# HTMLpurifier remove cc email between tags

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm using HTMLpurifier to sanitize inputs in my PHP application:

I have CC and BCC inputs something like:

Test Admin <test@domain.com>

when I do purify this string, it only keeps: Test Admin (without email between tags)

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you've got an escaping issue somewhere in your pipeline before HTML Purifier - something that's putting E-Mail text into an HTML context without HTML escaping it. HTML you need to purify that looks like this:

```html
<p><label for "id">Email</label><span id="email">Test Admin <test@domain.com></span></p>
```

...should really look like this:

```html
<p><label for "id">Email</label><span id="email">Test Admin &lt;test@domain.com&gt;</span></p>
```

If you have no control over the step that's inserting data *into* the HTML you ultimately want to purify before displaying, you can use this to preprocess your HTML before feeding it to HTML Purifier:

```php
$htmlWithEmail = preg_replace('/<([^<>@]*@[^<>@]*)>/', '&lt;${1}&gt;', $htmlWithEmail);
```

On the other hand - and I mention this because I know only a little bit about your use-case right now - if you're not actually trying to preserve HTML, if the string you're purifying is literally just `Test Admin <test@domain.com>` with nothing else (unlike the example I crafted above), `htmlspecialchars()` should be your weapon of choice when outputting into HTML, not HTML Purifier.

HTML Purifier's purpose is not all-purpose data sanitation, it really does exist only for the use-case where you have HTML, you *want to preserve it* if it's well-behaved, and then output it as HTML. You can find some more info about escaping for context here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641037/245790